# if it possible to have CSS of button tag to listen hover and active?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several html buttons and I have changed their appearance with CSS. Now I want to add some effects such as hover and active. I found hover and active for anchor `<a href="">` tags but not for `<button>` tags. Any suggestion or work around?

Comment: [dynamic-pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes). What you should read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `:hover` and `:active` work for buttons, at least in chrome and IE8  (all I have access to at the moment).

http://jsfiddle.net/j25ML/

```
button:hover{
   background-color: red;   
}

button:active{
   color: yellow;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `:active` and `:hover` pseudo-classes works on any element you want.

```
button:hover{
   background-color:red;   
}

button:active{
   background-color:blue;  
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Answer (score 1):

Applying state pseudo-elements (like :hover and :active ) is CSS 2.1 conformant and can be applied to any element. All modern browsers support this, including IE since version 7.

If you wan't to support IE6 or other very old browsers you should apply these pseudo-classes only to anchor <a> elements, because it causes problems otherwise.